# Alert with no message

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to make an Alert Dialog without message (only a title) in React Native?

Here is the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html

When I try to remove the message part ('My Alert Msg'), a [ts] error occurs (argument cannot be assigned to string parameter).

Can anyone help ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Put a blank body for the message.

```
Alert.alert( 'Alert Title', ' '
```

Comment: Ok but how do I remove the white space ?

Comment: Just put the apostrophe's you don't need the white space or do you mean the white space left where the message would be

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The white space left where the message would be, between the title and the buttons.